# Feedback "Till yet" - Is it correct?

Tags: word-usage

If I want to ask about Feedback till the present day, Is "Feedback **till yet**" valid grammatically or Feedback **till now** is more appropriate?

What are the applicable rules? Please share the right resource for this as I googled but couldn't find relevant resource.

Comment: Look into this thread '**[Yet vs Now](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic11415.html)**'

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use "till yet", you would use "'til now" as 'til is an abbreviated form of until. Alternatively you could say "Have we had any good feedback **yet**". till yet is completely incorrect and never used.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Yet* is not really a time expression, but rather a fuzzy duration expression, so you can't use it after *until* (or the shortened form *'til*, sometimes misspelled *till*).

Compare with an explicit expression of duration like "from Monday to Friday" or "since Thursday."

> I haven't done anything yet.
>
> I haven't done anything since Thursday.
>
> I haven't done anything from Monday to Friday.

You couldn't say "I haven't done anything until from Monday to Friday" or "I haven't done anything until since Thursday", for example.

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatic ways of saying your sentence fragment would be "Feedback to present", "Feedback so far", "Current Feedback", or "Feedback up to now".

*"Feedback till yet" is wrong and will likely baffle a native speaker.